# XSD Namespace backward compatibility

Tags: xsd, namespaces, compatibility

We are struggling with some namespace compatibility issues. Currently we store some external data in our database as XML files with namespace as **xmlns="http://xyz.com/prodresponse/v2"**, recently the vendor has changed the namesspace to **xmlns="http://xyz.com/prodresponse/v4"**.

The issue is we need to deal with both old and new namespace data seamlessly for our internal application purpose. I do see only one option at the momemnt:

1. Run a SQL script to convert existing xml data's from version v2 to v4.

Any other options?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the namespace changed is probably because the format has changed. Therefore, the namespace is very valuable information to you, as it tells you exactly what elements to expect and not to expect (when coupled with the corresponding XSD schema). The old XML data might very well be incorrect according to the schema if you update the namespace to the new version.

So no, I don't think you should change your existing XML data. Keep it, and make sure your parser knows how to handle both namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would run a SQL script to transform XML files...XML Transformations (XSLT) are doing a great job at this !

FunkyPeople wrote an interesting article about processing versioned XML files in Java. They present several approaches, and settle for this one:

- Apply successive XSLT stylesheets to convert input XML into the last schema version. Why multiple transformations? Because if you apply only one transformation, you'll have to maintain it when a newer schema version comes in. And you'll have to maintain *all* the transformations (v1 to vN, v2 to vN, v3 to vN, ...). If you apply incremental transformations one by one (v1 to v2, then v2 to v3, then v3 to v4), you'll only have to add one transformation each time a new schema is released.
- Perform processing on data respecting the last schema version only.
- If data was altered, apply reverse transformations to get back to the file's original version.

You can find the paper [here](http://www.funkypeople.biz/knowledge/) or [here](http://www.funkypeople.biz/knowledge/JavaXml-v2.pdf).